# regular expression for extracting user defined date formats

Tags: regex, date

I have a data set full of strings, I wanted to separate strings that contain Dates
I wrote the following regular expression to extract them:

```
print (re.findall(r'[Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?||April|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?]+\s\d+', x))
```

where x denotes the string under processing.
I wanted to obtain the following formats:
example:

```
December 2018
Feb 11-12
Feb 12-Mar 21
3rd Jan
February 12
```

however, some of the extra strings were also extracted. Like:

```
"Of 2017" from the string "BEST OF 2017"

"Line 1" from the string "Line 1"

"'addington 2" & "Paddington 2" from string "Paddington 2"

'hopping 3', 'as 20'
```

How do i fix these errors?

Comment: Before `April`, there is a typo `||`. Remove one of them you should get what you want

Comment: You should also replace the external `[]` with `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is a bit more complicated:

```
^(\d{1,2}\w{2} )?((Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|April|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)[- \d]*)+$
```

[Here's a full test](https://regex101.com/r/sy7iB0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Tested this at https://regex101.com/, work as expected

```
/Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|April|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?]+\s\d+/
```